# How do I animate through a bunch of "paged" views in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Say I have a bunch of views in a UIScrollView and I want each one to appear on the screen, one at a time, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your views are screen size, position them next to each other and set the pagingEnabled property to true, make sure the contentSize of the scoll view is wide enough for all of the views and then the user should be able to swipe through them one view at a time.  You could do it automatically with an NSTimer if you don't want the user to have to swipe.